# Not Seeing Robot in rviz

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working through the URDF Tutorial and one of the first things to do is to load a example file, 01-myfirst.urdf, into rviz for visualization.  So I load the example file as is, run the rviz launch file, rviz opens up, and the rviz grid is empty -- no robot!

I do get a warning message in rviz that says:

```
No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist
```

What does this mean?  What's missing?  Why can't I see the robot?

P.S.  I'm running Hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114811/not-seeing-robot-in-rviz/) by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2014-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would think this is a duplicate of [no robot visible in rviz for urdf tutorial](http://answers.ros.org/question/113561/no-robot-visible-in-rviz-for-urdf-tutorial).

Have you used the search?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on 2014-01-04**:
Thanks.  That was it!  Yes, I used the search but I did not come across that post.